# Document Management Model - Protecting Invariants

Tags: c#, oop, domain-driven-design

i am creating a light-weight document management system and have the following requirements.

- User can upload documents with a defined friendly name
- A document must maintain a history of revisions following a XX.YY.ZZ version numbering scheme
- Version numbers must be sequential and not duplicated within a document.
- When a document needs to be routed for approval no revisions are allowed to be made to the document

So the two invariants I need to enforce are the version numbering and locking down the document when it is awaiting approval.

I am torn between having Document and DocumentVersion two sepreate aggregate roots or having Document be the root with a collection (history) of document versions. The only thing that makes me think they are two seperate aggregate roots is because of the approval process of a document version. the entire history is not needed by the approver, just the document version itself.

thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> thoughts?

Immediate reaction is that you need to get a better understanding of the domain model.  This set of "requirements" looks more like somebody's guess at how things should be implemented than a description of the needs of the business.

> So the two invariants I need to enforce are the version numbering and locking down the document when it is awaiting approval.

Not necessarily - based on the the requirements you described, you don't need to lock down the document, you need to lock down the revision to its contents.

In other words, dig deeper; "Document" is trying to be too many different things", your domain language has nouns in it that you aren't using yet.

*Authors edit Drafts. (discussion of the Draft entity life cycle elided.) A satisfactory Draft may have a Version of its contents submitted for approval.  Approved submissions will be published as a Revision to a Document....*

In other words, both the editing process and the submission process have some state, which is to say an immutable value type hidden within them, replaced from time to time by the entity that is responsible for it.  You preserve your invariant by moving state, not entities, from one process to the next.

> The only thing that makes me think they are two seperate aggregate roots is because of the approval process of a document version. the entire history is not needed by the approver, just the document version itself.

Full points for identifying this conflict - it's the big clue that the current model is missing one or more significant ideas.

The "no revisions during approval" requirement is the big clue that the state being approved needs a different home from the entity that tracks the revision process.  No changes strongly implies state, and therefore value objects; entities are not satisfactory surrogates for state, because of their mutability.

Comment: thank you that was a wonderful explanation. based on what i described, can you give a quick aggregate recommendation? i have something now but i want to see how it aligns with your through process.

Answer (score 1):

I built a system very similar to this recently and we had the concept of a Draft. Every save operation resulted in a incremented version of the draft which copied the entire state. I.e immutable versioned drafts.

We then had the concept of a PublishedVersion - this was the same as your approved concept in that it was a 'this version of the draft is now becoming something the outside world can use'. Again we copied the entire state into this event. We could have just had a pointer to a draft from a published version as drafts were immutable anyway but decided to copy the state - trade of between simplicity and storage space.

We we just treating these things as events so would have a stream per aggregate with a projection off of the main stream for the PublishedVersion - by default we loaded the most recent published version in the UI.